# Always getting error "requestId is required" when doing POST on quickbooks payment API Apps Script

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, quickbooks

Im creating a script that will process a credit transaction and I always getting this response:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "code": "PMT-4002",
        "type": "invalid_request",
        "message": "requestId is required.",
        "detail": "requestId",
        "infoLink": "https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs?redirectID=PayErrors"
    }
  ]
}
```

Im trying to figure out where to put the "request-id" parameter on the request body. Here is my code:

```
function QBOcreatecharge(){

var token = "TOKEN"
var service = getQuickbooksService();

if (service.hasAccess()) {
var url = 'https://sandbox.api.intuit.com/quickbooks/v4/payments/charges'
var Details = 
{
"amount": "80.00",
"currency": "USD",
"capture": "false",
"token": token
}

var params = {
headers: {
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
},
contentType:  'application/json',    
method: 'POST',
payload: JSON.stringify(Details),
muteHttpExceptions:true
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

var value = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
Logger.log(value)
}
else{
var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);    
}

}
```

How do I add the requestId parameter? I tried to insert it on the link, on the header and nothing work. Im using UrlFetch on Google Apps Script. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try adding it to the details. Consult their API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Request-Id` is a *header* you need to send. e.g.:

```
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
  'Request-Id': your unique value here 
},
```

Intuit documents it here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbpayments/docs/develop/explore-the-quickbooks-payments-api/rest-api-features#identifiers